# Android memory leak exception

Tags: java, android, performance, android-bitmap

I catch an exception out of memory in android when changing Activity or creating Bitmap object in Android  What should I do either to finish the current activity or do something else ? Since Java has garbage collector, so I thought I don’t have to delete objects manually.

```
try {
    // done something that causing memory leak
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    // what should I do here  
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you can change heapsize.

Comment: I really strongly suggest you to watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk  (one hour... but it is a really good talk a bout tracking memory leak on Android)

Comment: You can't really do anything in the catch block. You have the find the root cause and fix it.

Comment: A garbage collector can only collects objects that your program holds zero references to, somewhere in your program you are referencing large objects like bitmaps that eventually causes you to exceed the maximum memory limit.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc of `Error`:

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application **should not try to catch**. Most such errors are abnormal conditions.

When the `OutOfMemoryError` occurs, the damage is already done. Instead of catching this error, you should identify and resolve the problem in your application.

When you create bitmap objects, possible causes may be that the size of this bitmap is simply too large, or you create too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so much about this as many members already said. Find the root cause and fix. One thing you can do is to increase the heap size by applying this in your manifest.xml

```
<application
.
.
.
   android:largeHeap="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with bitmaps is so sensitive, there are many things any one must know about dealing with them, If you're not careful, bitmaps can quickly consume your available memory budget leading to an application crash.

I think you should read and follow this article about "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently", to know how to load, cache, process and manage bitmaps in correct way.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html